# Add row from DataGridViewRowCollection c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So, I have a problem.

I want to dynamically change the `DataGridViewRow` By wrapping all it's content by using `List<DataGridViewRowCollection>`. Here's some snippets

```cs
public List<DataGridViewRowCollection> colTrx = new List<DataGridViewRowCollection>();
     // By using colTrx As List, I can add some row collections by added into it

public int pointerGrid = 0;

public void createDatas()
{
    if(gridTab.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
       colTrx.add(someGrid.Rows);
       point += 1;
    }
}

public void getData()
{
     if(someGrid.Rows.Count != 0)
     {
        someGrid.Rows.Clear();
     }
     else
     {
        DataGridViewRowCollection ollColl = colTrx[pointerGrid - 1];

        foreach (DataGridViewRow kkk in ollColl.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
        {
            someGrid.Add(kkk);
        }

        //Something wrong here, it won't add row from DataGridViewRowCollection

        pointerGrid -= 1;
    }
}
```

The goal is :


1. Set data by add some row from `someGrid` into `colTrx`

2. Clear rows from `someGrid`

3. When user trigger a button, get a data from `colTrx[pointerGrid - 1]`,

4. And set the Rows From it

How I can achieve this?

Comment: DataGridRow**Collection** is already a collection. You are building a List of a collection. Probably you want a **List<DataGridRow>** instead

Comment: Of course!. But, every collection are different from the other. So i made List<DataGridViewCollection> to hold different rowset :)

Comment: can you provide more information ? like if it gives you an error or something?

Comment: There's no error so far. But, if I add directly, let's say ```someGrid.Add(colTrx);``` without ```DataGridViewRow``` loops, It will return single rows contains something like ```System.Collections.Generic``` etc etc